# Spurious error? "Argument of \genfrac has an extra }." with \usepackage{breqn}

Tags: equations, breqn

The equation below compiled fine the other day, and now it doesn't, giving the error in the subject heading. If I delete the equation the whole document compiles just fine.

The glitch started when, to accommodate a different long equation in the same document, I added `\usepackage{breqn}` and use `dmath` for that one long equation. If I comment out `\usepackage{breqn}`, all works fine.  But no problems with/without this package on other equations.  I've never encountered anything quite like this.

```
\begin{equation}
  U(x_h, Y) = \left(
    \alpha Y^\frac{\theta - 1}{\theta} + (1 - \alpha)
    \left(
      \sum_{h = 1}^n \beta_h x_h^\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}
    \right)^{\frac{\theta - 1}{\theta}/\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}}
  \right)^\frac{\theta}{\theta - 1} 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Please make this into a complete (but minimal) working example by including the `\documentclass` through `\end{document}` so that we can reproduce the error.  It takes a bit more work on your part, but saves everyone else that much time, which is a net gain.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Just because you can get away with `x^\frac{y}{z}` (and even `x^\frac yz` doesn't make it a good idea. I urge you to move towards `x^{y}` particularly if `y` is more than one character to reduce the chances of errors. Also, while I can understand people arguing `x^y` is more readable than `x^{y}` due to the clutter of the braces, in the case of something like `\alpha Y^\frac{\theta - 1}{\theta} + (1 - \alpha)` it's not obvious what's superscript and what's not

Answer (score 4):

The fact that `x^\frac{1}{2}` works for the default primitive superscript parsing is an accident of the definition of `\frac` that should never be used  in document markup.

For any command that you can define with `\newcommand` or `\def` the rule would be that if you omit the braces the next token is taken as a brace in which case

```
x^\frac{1}{2}
```

would be equivalent to

```
x^{\frac} {1}{2}
```

where it is clear that `\frac` has no arguments and when parsing for arguments will see the end of the superscript and generate the `extra }` error seen in the title.

this is exactly what is happening here, `breqn` makes many characters "math active" and gives them macro definitions so `^` picks up its arguments using macro argument rules. For any normal document using a single letter or a braced expression this makes no difference, but you see the difference if you rely on the hidden internal brace group as generated by `\frac` which is available to the primitive superscript list parsing, but not to macro argument parsing.

this works without error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  U(x_h, Y) = \left(
    \alpha Y^{\frac{\theta - 1}{\theta}} + (1 - \alpha)
    \left(
      \sum_{h = 1}^n \beta_h x_h^{\frac{\sigma - 1}{\sigma}}
    \right)^{\frac{\theta - 1}{\theta}/\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}}
  \right)^{\frac{\theta}{\theta - 1}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```